# Submit/log in click Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, submit, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to auto submit login details and then log in to a page.

My code snippet thus far is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome("PathOfChromeDriver")


driver.get("URL")

username = driver.find_element_by_name("UserName")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("Password")

username.send_keys("My_Username")
password.send_keys("My_Password")
```

The above snippet works fine. The problem is submitting/ pressing login:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("Sign in").click()
```

I have tried every conceivable variation i could find on this forum of the above such as:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

etc.

The source code to the website element in question is:

```
<form action="/Account/SignIn?returnUrl=%252fProducts" method="post" id="page-root" class="signin-page local-new-style" autocomplete="off">

<div class="login">
    <img alt="logo" src="/Content/images/bg_login_logo.png" />
    <div class="inner_content ">
        <div class="content">

            <h1>Access your account</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="UserName" placeholder="Login" />

            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" />

            </div>

            <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" value="True" />
                    Remember my login on this computer
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

I just cannot get it to work. It usually gives me an error of the type "unable to locate an element with the ZZZ expression YYY".

Any input is appreciated and the person with a solution is nothing short of a Hero!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[id='page-root'] button").click()
```

This should also work:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("page-root").submit()
```

Comment: Yes! it works! So I guess the reason why my attempts were unsuccessful is because I need to refer back to the "ultimate parent of the tree", if that makes sense? 

Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. You were searching for a name 'submit', but submit is the type of the submit button. Your xpath search for 'Sign in' also did not work because it is invalid xpath. You can indeed refer back to the ultimate parent, but it isn't always necessary. I usually search for items with an id (which is unique) and go from there. The following link explains a bit more about css selectors: https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors